# Supporting Hyper-Threading technology by motherboards for Intel core i7 CPUs

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I want to buy ASUS P8Z77-V LX motherboard but on Asus website there as no information about supporting Hyper-Threading technology. I want to buy INTEL core i7 CPU, this CPU supports this technology. If I want to use a Hyper-Threading for my needs shall I buy a Hyper-Threading supporting motherboard?

Comment: The motherboard's online support documents in question clearly indicates that it supports ALL of Intel's Sandybridge and Ivybridge i7 CPUs provided the proper BIOS revision is used.

Answer (score 0):

All Intel motherboards of recent vintage support Hyper-Threading. The last time you had to make sure your motherboard did was the Pentium 4 days.

Comment: Im sorry, my english is poor because my native language is not English. In the last sentence you said that this motherboard must not be old. Yes?

Comment: Correct. Hyper-Threading first appeared in the Pentium 4 in the year 2002.

Comment: @Bert - You should clarify your statement.  The motherboard has nothing to do with Intel's Hyper-Threading.  The only question that determines of Hyper-Threading is supported is if the CPU supports it.  Of course the motherboard has to support the CPU installed, which is normally determined by the BIOS revision, which can be updated provided you also have an already supported CPU.